# Naming convention for Grails plugins with hyphenated names

Tags: grails, groovy, configuration

I want my Grails app (`myapp`) to use a plugin that I'm developing called `grails-myapp-auth`.

I create the plugin using standard Grails targets:

```
grails create-plugin myapp-auth
```

And then began developing it.

In `myapp`'s `BuildConfig.groovy I specify the local location of the plugin via:

```
grails.plugin.location.myapp-auth = '../../../myapp-auth'
```

However this gives me:

```
| Error WARNING: Inline plugins for [myapp] cannot be read due to error: startup failed:
/home/myuser/sandbox/eclipse/workspace/myapp/myapp/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy: 4: 
(grails.plugin.location.myapp - auth) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression at line: 4 column: 39. File: /home/myuser/sandbox/eclipse/workspace/myapp/myapp/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy @ line 4, column 39.
    grails.plugin.location.myapp-auth = '../../../myapp-auth'
```

So it looks like Grails is trying to evaluate the config as a binary expression like so:

```
<Some Value>                  -  <Another Value> =  <Yet Another Value>
grails.plugin.location.myapp  -  auth            =  '../../../myapp-auth'
```

What can I do to fix this. If at all possible I'd like to keep the plugin called `myapp-auth` but could put a clothes pin on my nose and shorten it to just `myappauth` if absolute need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
grails.plugin.location.'myapp-auth' = '../../../myapp-auth'
```

Comment: is correct.  To elaborate a bit, in Groovy if you have something like plugin.location.myapp-auth='../../../myapp-auth', the hyphen there is interpreted as the subtraction operator.  You are subtracting the value of "auth" from the value of "plugin.location.myapp".  I hope that makes sense.